# Почему не обновляется виджет с чатом QListWidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Есть такой код, для простоты лишнее не привожу. После авторизации срабатывает метод getChat и выводится виджет с сообщениями, которые берутся из базы. В другом потоке отправляются запросы на сервер каждую секунду и в консоли вижу, что нужный словарь с данными при отправке нового сообщения как и нужно обновляется и возвращается в переменной rs. Далее пытаюсь перерисовать виджет с сообщениями, наверное это нужно делать в методе on_request, но не получается. Прошу подсказать, ума не приложу, как это реализовать.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
import requests
import json
import time

colors = ['#1f3a93', '#26a65b']

class ThreadClass(QThread):
    about_response = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, url: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.url = url

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                rs = requests.post(self.url)
                self.about_response.emit(rs)

            except Exception as e:
                print('Error:', e)

            finally:
                time.sleep(3)

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.url_base = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
        self.main_id = 0
        self.res_usr = {}
        self.chat_obj = QtWidgets.QListWidget


        url = self.url_base + 'blog/chat'

        self.thread_class = ThreadClass(url)
        self.thread_class.about_response.connect(self.on_response)
        self.thread_class.start()

        self.title = QtWidgets.QLabel('Авторизация')
        self.title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        self.username = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.username.setPlaceholderText('Введите логин:')
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.password.setPlaceholderText('Введите пароль:'),
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.btnLogin = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&OK")

        self.lnkReg = QtWidgets.QPushButton('&Регистрация')

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.title)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.username)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.password)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnLogin)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lnkReg)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.btnLogin.clicked.connect(self.authorisation)
        self.lnkReg.clicked.connect(self.switchToRegistration)

    def on_response(self, rs):
        res_u = rs.text
        res_pst = json.loads(res_u)
        print(res_pst)
        self.chat_obj = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        for key, value in res_pst.items():
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.chat_obj)
            item.setText(value[0] + ': ' + value[1])
            if value[2] == self.main_id:
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
                item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(colors[0]))
            else:
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
                item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(colors[1]))
            self.chat_obj.addItem(value[0] + ': ' + value[1])
        self.chat_obj.repaint()



    def switchToRegistration(self):
        """
        Переключение на регистрацию
        """
        window.resize(300, 200)
        self.clearLayout(self.vbox)

        self.title = QtWidgets.QLabel('Регистрация')
        self.title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        self.username = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.username.setPlaceholderText('Введите логин:')
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.password.setPlaceholderText('Введите пароль:'),
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.btnReg = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&OK")

        self.lnkAutor = QtWidgets.QPushButton('&Авторизация')

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.title)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.username)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.password)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnReg)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lnkAutor)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.btnReg.clicked.connect(self.registration)
        self.lnkAutor.clicked.connect(self.switchToAuthorisation)


    def switchToAuthorisation(self):
        """
        Переключение на авторизацию
        """
        window.resize(300, 200)
        self.clearLayout(self.vbox)

        self.title = QtWidgets.QLabel('Авторизация')
        self.title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        self.username = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.username.setPlaceholderText('Введите логин:')
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.password.setPlaceholderText('Введите пароль:'),
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.btnAutor = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&OK")

        self.lnkReg = QtWidgets.QPushButton('&Регистрация')

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.title)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.username)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.password)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnLogin)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lnkReg)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.btnAutor.clicked.connect(self.authorisation)
        self.lnkReg.clicked.connect(self.switchToRegistration)


    def authorisation(self):
        """
        Авторизация
        """
        url = self.url_base + 'auth/login'
        data = {'username': self.username.text(), 'password': self.password.text()}
        r = requests.post(url, json=data)

        res_u = r.text
        #print(res_u)
        res_usr = json.loads(res_u)
        #print(res_usr['status'])
        if res_usr['status'] == 'ok':
            self.main_id = res_usr['id']
            #print(self.main_id)
            self.getChat()
        elif res_usr['status'] == 'no':
            self.showError(res_usr)


    def registration(self):
        """
        Регистрация
        """
        url = self.url_base + 'auth/register'
        data = {'username': self.username.text(), 'password': self.password.text()}
        r = requests.post(url, json=data)

        res_u = r.text
        #print(res_u)
        res_usr = json.loads(res_u)
        if res_usr['status'] == 'ok':
            self.switchToAuthorisation()
        elif res_usr['status'] == 'no':
            self.showError(res_usr)


    def clearLayout(self, layout):
        """
        Очистка окошка
        """
        for i in reversed(range(layout.count())):
            layout.itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)


    def showError(self, res_usr):
        """
        Показать ошибки
        """
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(res_usr['error'])
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)

    def showSuccess(self, res_usr):
        """
        Показать успех
        """
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(res_usr['success_msg'])
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)

    def getChat(self):
        window.resize(300, 400)
        self.clearLayout(self.vbox)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Чат')
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)

        url = self.url_base + 'blog/chat'
        r = requests.post(url)
        print(r.status_code, r.reason)
        print(r.request.headers)

        res_u = r.text
        res_pst = json.loads(res_u)
        #print(res_pst)

        self.chat_obj = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        for key, value in res_pst.items():
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.chat_obj)
            item.setText(value[0] + ': ' + value[1])
            if value[2] == self.main_id:
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
                item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(colors[0]))
            else:
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
                item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(colors[1]))
        #self.chat_obj.addItem(value[0] + ': ' + value[1])

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.chat_obj)

        self.message = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.message.setPlaceholderText('Введите сообщение')
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.message)

        self.btnSend = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Отправить")
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnSend)
        self.btnSend.clicked.connect(self.sendmessage)


    def sendmessage(self):
        """
        Отправка сообщения
        """
        print(self.main_id)
        url = self.url_base + 'blog/create/{}'.format(self.main_id)
        data = {'message': self.message.text()}
        #print(data)
        r = requests.post(url, json=data)

        #print(r.status_code, r.reason)
        #print(r.request.headers)

        res_m = r.text
        #print(res_m)
        res_usr = json.loads(res_m)
        if res_usr['status'] == 'ok':
            self.showSuccess(res_usr)
        elif res_usr['status'] == 'no':
            self.showError(res_usr)

        self.message.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("Простой Мессенжер")
    window.resize(300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот код серверной части, тот, который отвечает за формирование чата:

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
)
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort

from flaskr.auth import login_required
from flaskr.db import get_db
import json

bp = Blueprint('blog', __name__, url_prefix='/blog')


@bp.route('/chat', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def chat():
    db = get_db()
    posts = db.execute(
        'SELECT p.id, author_id, msg, created, u.username'
        ' FROM post p JOIN user u'
        ' ON u.id = p.author_id'
        ' ORDER BY p.created DESC',
    ).fetchall()
    pst = {}
    for i in posts:
        pst[i['id']] = [i['username'], i['msg'], i['author_id']]
    dc = pst
    dc = json.dumps(dc)
    return dc

@bp.route('/create/<main_id>', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def create(main_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg = request.get_json().get('message')
        error = None

        if not msg:
            error = 'Message is required.'

        if error is not None:
            dc = {'error': error, 'status': 'not'}
            dc = json.dumps(dc)
            return dc
        else:
            db = get_db()
            author_id = main_id
            db.execute(
                'INSERT INTO post (msg, author_id)'
                ' VALUES (?, ?)',
                (msg, author_id)
            )
            db.commit()

            dc = {'success_msg': 'The message successfully sent', 'status': 'ok'}
            dc = json.dumps(dc)
            return dc

    return dc
```

Comment: `getChat` нигде не вызывается. Кст, зачем на каждый чих создавать список (я про `self.chat_obj`)? Его нужно один раз создать и после в него добавлять элементы

Comment: gil9red, метод getChat вызывается при авторизации, просто я эту часть кода не привел) кстати да, список я формирую в методе getChat и еще раз в другом месте при попытке перерисовать, понимаю, что это не правильно

Comment: ThreadClass и on_response судя по коду ни на что не влияют? А в getChat в список элементы не добавляются. А так, QListWidget должен быть только один. Не нужно и нет смысла его пересоздавать. Перерисовывать тоже не нужно -- он сам обновляется после изменений в себе. `json.loads` тоже не нужно у ответа из `requests` есть метод `rs.json()`. Назначение `self.clearLayout` тоже вызывает вопросы :) Кст, а где `self.vbox`  создается?

Comment: Благодаря ThreadClass и on_response я в консоли вижу, что приходят данные в переменной rs, вот с этими данными я пытаюсь обновить тот виджет, который формируется в getChat. На данный момент картина такая, что у меня есть сформированное окошко с чатом и приходящая переменная rs, вот никак не удается соединить их. Я пытался вызвать метод on_response внутри метода getChat, но там на входе переменная rs требуется, а ее не получается при вызове getChat передать

Comment: self.vbox при инициализации mainWindow создается, а self.clearLayout - это я забыл удалить:)

Comment: Актуализируйте код в вопросе, пожалуйста, а то вам невозможно будет помочь ) Кст, у вас написано что новые данные берете из базы, но в коде нет работы с базой -- только http запросы

Comment: Привел весь код, за исключением серверной части, извиняюсь за лишние методы, которые не имеют к вопросу отношения. Метод self.clearLayout  я использую для очистки окошка от элементов при переключении на случай авторизации, регистрации или вывода сообщений - не знаю насколько это оправдано.

Comment: Это очень костыльно. Я бы сделал отдельное окно с авторизацией и отдельное окно с чатом и после авторизации менял их. Например через QStackedWidget, [пример_1](https://github.com/gil9red/audio_player_vk/tree/6c03176abdd4b4bd13edde73a5b1361326df9211) и [пример_2](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/2a859f7d2495e8c7e91567fa99e21e3b454dd62e/game__guess_the_number/gui__pyqt)

Comment: Спасибо, позже так и переделаю, сейчас бы мне понять как список обновлять

Comment: Добавил код серверной части, он на основе Flask

Comment: А нужно список дополнять или очищать и заполнять?

Comment: Дополнять, по мере накопления

Comment: Моя мысль это убрать из getChat формирование виджета списка и вызывать внутри этого метода метод on_response , но проблема с тем, что тогда нужно в getChat передавать переменную rs, но при вызове самого getChat выдает ошибку, что в mainWindow нет переменной rs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мои изменения рядом с `# TODO:`. Главное что сделал – убрал пересоздание виджета-списка и манипуляции с layout (это можно потом сделать, сейчас это будет мешать)

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.url_base = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
        self.main_id = 0
        self.res_usr = dict()

        # TODO:
        # self.chat_obj = QtWidgets.QListWidget


        url = self.url_base + 'blog/chat'

        self.thread_class = ThreadClass(url)
        self.thread_class.about_response.connect(self.on_response)
        self.thread_class.start()

        self.title = QtWidgets.QLabel('Авторизация')
        self.title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        self.username = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.username.setPlaceholderText('Введите логин:')
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.password.setPlaceholderText('Введите пароль:'),
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.btnLogin = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&OK")

        self.lnkReg = QtWidgets.QPushButton('&Регистрация')

        self.chat_obj = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.title)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.username)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.password)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnLogin)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lnkReg)

        # TODO:
        # Пусть пока будет
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.chat_obj)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.btnLogin.clicked.connect(self.authorisation)
        self.lnkReg.clicked.connect(self.switchToRegistration)

    def on_response(self, rs):
        # TODO:
        res_pst = rs.json()
        # res_u = rs.text
        # res_pst = json.loads(res_u)
        print(res_pst)

        for key, value in res_pst.items():
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.chat_obj)
            item.setText(value[0] + ': ' + value[1])
            if value[2] == self.main_id:
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
                item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(colors[0]))
            else:
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
                item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(colors[1]))

            self.chat_obj.addItem(value[0] + ': ' + value[1])

    def switchToRegistration(self):
        """
        Переключение на регистрацию
        """
        # TODO:
        self.resize(300, 200)
        # self.clearLayout(self.vbox)

        self.title = QtWidgets.QLabel('Регистрация')
        self.title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        self.username = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.username.setPlaceholderText('Введите логин:')
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.password.setPlaceholderText('Введите пароль:'),
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.btnReg = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&OK")

        self.lnkAutor = QtWidgets.QPushButton('&Авторизация')

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.title)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.username)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.password)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnReg)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lnkAutor)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.btnReg.clicked.connect(self.registration)
        self.lnkAutor.clicked.connect(self.switchToAuthorisation)


    def switchToAuthorisation(self):
        """
        Переключение на авторизацию
        """
        # TODO:
        self.resize(300, 200)
        # self.clearLayout(self.vbox)

        self.title = QtWidgets.QLabel('Авторизация')
        self.title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        self.username = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.username.setPlaceholderText('Введите логин:')
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.password.setPlaceholderText('Введите пароль:'),
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.btnAutor = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&OK")

        self.lnkReg = QtWidgets.QPushButton('&Регистрация')

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.title)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.username)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.password)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnLogin)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lnkReg)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.btnAutor.clicked.connect(self.authorisation)
        self.lnkReg.clicked.connect(self.switchToRegistration)


    def authorisation(self):
        """
        Авторизация
        """
        url = self.url_base + 'auth/login'
        data = {'username': self.username.text(), 'password': self.password.text()}
        r = requests.post(url, json=data)
        # TODO:
        res_usr = r.json()
        # res_u = r.text
        # #print(res_u)
        # res_usr = json.loads(res_u)
        #print(res_usr['status'])
        if res_usr['status'] == 'ok':
            self.main_id = res_usr['id']
            #print(self.main_id)
            self.getChat()
        elif res_usr['status'] == 'no':
            self.showError(res_usr)


    def registration(self):
        """
        Регистрация
        """
        url = self.url_base + 'auth/register'
        data = {'username': self.username.text(), 'password': self.password.text()}
        r = requests.post(url, json=data)
        res_usr = r.json()
        # TODO:
        # res_u = r.text
        # #print(res_u)
        # res_usr = json.loads(res_u)
        if res_usr['status'] == 'ok':
            self.switchToAuthorisation()
        elif res_usr['status'] == 'no':
            self.showError(res_usr)

    # TODO: 
    # def clearLayout(self, layout):
    #     """
    #     Очистка окошка
    #     """
    #     for i in reversed(range(layout.count())):
    #         layout.itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)


    def showError(self, res_usr):
        """
        Показать ошибки
        """
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(res_usr['error'])
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)

    def showSuccess(self, res_usr):
        """
        Показать успех
        """
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(res_usr['success_msg'])
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)

    def getChat(self):
        window.resize(300, 400)
        # self.clearLayout(self.vbox)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Чат')
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)

        url = self.url_base + 'blog/chat'
        r = requests.post(url)
        print(r.status_code, r.reason)
        print(r.request.headers)

        # TODO:
        res_pst = r.json()
        # res_u = r.text
        # res_pst = json.loads(res_u)
        #print(res_pst)

        # self.chat_obj = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        for key, value in res_pst.items():
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.chat_obj)
            item.setText(value[0] + ': ' + value[1])
            if value[2] == self.main_id:
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
                item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(colors[0]))
            else:
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
                item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(colors[1]))
        #self.chat_obj.addItem(value[0] + ': ' + value[1])

        # TODO: в конструкторе добавлено на форму
        # self.vbox.addWidget(self.chat_obj)

        self.message = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.message.setPlaceholderText('Введите сообщение')
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.message)

        self.btnSend = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Отправить")
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnSend)
        self.btnSend.clicked.connect(self.sendmessage)


    def sendmessage(self):
        """
        Отправка сообщения
        """
        print(self.main_id)
        url = self.url_base + 'blog/create/{}'.format(self.main_id)
        data = {'message': self.message.text()}
        #print(data)
        r = requests.post(url, json=data)

        #print(r.status_code, r.reason)
        #print(r.request.headers)

        # TODO:
        res_usr = r.json()
        # res_m = r.text
        # #print(res_m)
        # res_usr = json.loads(res_m)
        if res_usr['status'] == 'ok':
            self.showSuccess(res_usr)
        elif res_usr['status'] == 'no':
            self.showError(res_usr)

        self.message.clear()
```

---

Код с `self.label =`  явно костыльный, но его не трогал, т.к. проблема с `QListWidget`, а не с этим

Comment: gil9red, спасибо, добрый человек, благодаря вам я много нового узнал и программа заработала)

Comment: @ZaurK, вы молодец что сами после разобрались :)